# What is the suitable way to create a one-to-one chat between business user and customer with laravel and websockets?

Tags: laravel, chat

I am looking for a chat system, where business users can select other users to chat with, whereas the user can only chat with the business owner and not other user simultaneously. I am building an app as such with laravel and websockets. I'm guessing most work is to be done in vueJs or any such framework. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: you can use pusher and vue with laravel

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/